# MediaElement.buffered IndexSizeError

Tags: javascript

I try to get the buffered parts of media element (specifically I try to get it from a `video` element, but I want it to be able to use `audio` too), but when I use the `start()` or `end()` functions with some offset (for example, `0`), The log returns the following error:

> IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount

What's wrong with my code?

```
var mediaelement = function(e) {
    return e.buffered.start(0);
}

console.log(mediaelement(document.querySelector('video')));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, there is nothing buffered yet when you call your function.
You should add a check to `e.buffered.length` before calling `TimeRanges.start()` or `TimeRanges.end()`:

```js
function getbufferedstart(el) {
  if(el.buffered.length) {
    return el.buffered.start(0);
  }
  else {
    return 'avoided a throw';
  }
}
   
var a = new Audio('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8c9m92u1euqnkaz/GershwinWhiteman-RhapsodyInBluePart1.mp3');
a.onloadedmetadata = onwehavebufferedsomething;

console.log(getbufferedstart(a)); // avoided
console.log('really ?');
a.buffered.start(0); // Error

function onwehavebufferedsomething(evt) {
  console.log("now it's ok");
  console.log(getbufferedstart(a));  // 0
}
```

```css
body>.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100vh}
```

Comment: It was awesome and solved my problem. Thank you very much!